# What is the Java networking method that can be used to simulate breaking a socket?

Tags: java, networking

My teacher told me that there's a Java networking method (I think either urgentByte or sendByte ) , which can be used to break a socket connection.  However, it is not actually meant to do this.

For example, if we have an Echo client and server pair - you would call this method from a third program ; and it would  break the connection.

If anyone knew, I would greatly appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Really, so you could just terminate other peoples connections?

Comment: You should ask your teacher what he's talking about, or whether you have misunderstood. Neither of the methods you mentioned exists, and there is no other such Java method that can break a connection between two other parties either.

Comment: @EJP  - Understood, I will clarify with him . thanks !!